# @nestjs/swagger generate query object for GET request

Tags: swagger, nestjs, openapi, openapi-generator, nestjs-swagger

I have 2 routes, one is POST, it uses `@ApiBody` decorator and works correctly, the other one is GET, and I don't know what decorators should I use for generating the correct api.

```
class ImagesRequestDto {
  @ApiProperty({ type: String })
  @IsOptional()
  srch?: string

  @ApiProperty({ type: Number })
  @IsOptional()
  @Min(0)
  offset?: number

  @ApiProperty({ type: Number })
  @IsOptional()
  @Min(0)
  @Max(1000)
  limit?: number
}

// This one works:
@ApiBody({ type: ImagesRequestDto })
@ApiResponse({ status: 200, type: ImagesResponseDto })
@Post('list-post')
async listPost(@Req() request: Request, @Body() filter: ImagesRequestDto): Promise<ImagesResponseDto> {
  const [images, count] = await this.imagesService.getUserImages(filter)
  request.res.status(200)
  return { images, count }
}

// This one generates incorrect openapi:
@ApiQuery(ImagesRequestDto)
// Or @ApiQuery({ type: ImagesRequestDto, name: 'filter' })
@ApiResponse({ type: ImagesResponseDto })
@Get('list-get')
async listGet(@Query() filter: ImagesRequestDto): Promise<ImagesResponseDto> {
  const [images, count] = await this.imagesService.getUserImages(filter)
  return { images, count } 
}
```

I generate openapi.json with `@nestjs/swagger` and then run `nswag` to generate `api.ts` file for the front-end. The result is:

```
listPost(body: ImagesRequestDto, cancelToken?: CancelToken | undefined): Promise<ImagesResponseDto> {
   ...axios request post...
}

listGet(srch: string, offset: number, limit: number, imagesRequestDto: any , cancelToken?: CancelToken | undefined): Promise<ImagesResponseDto> {
   ...axios request get...
}
```

So it has `imagesRequestDto: any` (why?) and some destructured arguments from imagesRequestDto.
I want `listGet` to accept the same arguments as `listPost` - there should 2 arguments, the first one is `query: ImagesRequestDto`, the second is `cancelToken`. That is much more convenient (especially with many filtering arguments) since this case it can be used by

```
const images = await imagesClient.listGet(ImagesRequestDto.fromJS({..specify only required arguments..}))
```

instead of

```
const images = await imagesClient.listGet(srch, first, second, third, ..., offset, limit)
```

Is it possible to achieve or is there any limitation for get requests in openapi?